# ruby on rails active admin gem - how do I display first name and last name of my users

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I installed the active admin gem in my rails 4 project. Works great....

But the columns 'First name' and 'Last name' are empty - the columns are there, but they're empty. When a person signs up to my app with devise the fields they have to fill in are:

```
first name
second name
email
password
confirm password
```

The email and password columns appear in my active admin, with the relevant user details listed in those columns, but nothing for first name and second name. Any ideas on how I can get this information to show up in my Admin side?

On closer inspection, my problem is more deep rooted, I think. In Rails console, when I do User.last, I get:

```
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
 => #<User id: 3, email: "jimcollins@gmail.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$mOSzzXy1SZxQ1gVQbUqG9uQsam0YnaiLzXOJYne3aI58...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 2, current_sign_in_at: "2014-03-03 13:16:10", last_sign_in_at: "2014-03-03 13:12:16", current_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", last_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", created_at: "2014-03-03 13:12:16", updated_at: "2014-03-03 13:17:07", first_name: nil, last_name: nil, provider: nil, uid: nil, name: nil, oauth_token: nil, oauth_expires_at: nil> 
2.0.0p247 :003 >
```

So first_name and last_name are 'nil'. Where should I set the values for these? Sorry, quite a beginner at Rails...

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say for sure what the problem is without seeing *any* of the code in your ActiveAdmin registers. If users are entering this information in a form field, but it's not getting saved it's most likely an issue with Rails 4's strong parameters. If users are *registering* there is likely a problem with you not permitting the `first_name` and `last_name` parameters on that form's controller. If you are adding these users in manually from the `user` admin panel, you will want to make sure you are adding `first_name` and `last_name` to the `permit_params` method call in your register.

Comment: thanks for that, figured it out and I'm going to post the exact code for others on how I got it working. Had to do with strong parameters alright. Now, any idea how I can get the first_name and last_name of people who log in with Facebook? :)

Comment: in fact, Facebook first_name and last_name was easy enough:          user.first_name = auth.info.first_name and user.last_name = auth.info.last_name in find_for_facebook_auth method

Answer (score 1):

Using Rails 4, Ruby 2.0, and having installed Devise, I made my application controller look like this, and now I get `first_name` and `last_name` stored in my database:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

   before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :first_name, :last_name) }

   # might need the code below for account updating
   # devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :firstname, :lastname) }
  end

end
```